# How to Keep Cookie Value after page refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm creating a demo panel for users to change the layout of a Wordpress theme when they arrive at my demo site.  The user changes value via a select drop-down box, and a cookie is set at that time.

I'm having trouble showing the ACTIONS that I want implement after the page is refreshed.  So the cookie is saving it's value, but after page refresh my CSS actions will not stay in place.  I'm not very good with jQuery so any help would be appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
$('#montage-demo-panel select.body-style-layout').change(function () {

        // Apply cookie
        $.cookie('body-style-layout', $(this).val(), { path: '/' });

                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (value == 'fixed') {
                    var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
                    var header = $('#header');
                    var masthead = $('#masthead');
                    var branding = $('#branding');

                    wrapper.removeAttr('style');
                    header.removeAttr('style');
                    masthead.removeAttr('style');
                    branding.removeAttr('style');

                    wrapper.removeClass('wrapper-full purple-header-full');
                    header.removeClass('header-full');
                    masthead.removeClass('masthead-full');
                    branding.removeClass('branding-full');
                    location.reload();

                   } else {

                    var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
                    var header = $('#header');
                    var masthead = $('#masthead');
                    var branding = $('#branding');
                    var mainbg = $('#main-bg');
                    var access = $('#access');

                    wrapper.removeClass('purple-header');

                    wrapper.addClass('wrapper-full purple-header-full');
                    header.addClass('header-full');
                    masthead.addClass('masthead-full');
                    branding.addClass('branding-full');
                    mainbg.addClass('main-bg-full');
                    access.addClass('access-full');

        // Re-fresh page
        location.reload();
                }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure cookie value is not exist anymore after page refresh ?

Comment: I'm sorry about being unclear - the cookie value does remain - but the CSS values are not staying in place - it's just like I refresh the page and it reverts back to original values.  But the actual cookie value itself is staying the same.

Comment: do you implement the style by just removing-adding class in your `change()` event ??

Comment: yes, i think that is what i'm doing, but is that wrong?  I don't know how to get the actions I want.

Comment: I created an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... if you're just applying the style on `change();` event, it's definitely wont affect on page refresh. I suggest check the cookie value everytime page refresh, like:

```
$(function(){
   var cookieval = $.cookie('cookie-key');
   if (cookieval === 'something'){
      //here implement style according to 'something'
   } else {
      //here implement another style
   }
});
```

good luck !!

**UPDATE :**

1. place the code above anywhere in your page;
2. just only do set cookie and reload on select change; like:

   ```
    $('#montage-demo-panel select.body-style-layout').change(function () {
       $.cookie('body-style-layout', $(this).val(), { path: '/' });
       location.reload();
    }
   ```
3. done.

Comment: Charlie, how can I call `select.body-style` and implement it with your answer?  I'm confused as to how to do that.

Comment: Fantastic, Charles!  It took a while, but it worked finally.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Congrats. glad can help ! :)